# Accessing Additional Results in google places search

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

Hi to all

I am trying to get places from [The Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/).

for the first time I got the first 20 result but when I use it second time with the request `"next_page_token"` like this :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?page_token=CkQ3AAAADjez7YyK689hZ1LwKAvXMEEuoMNwFn7tAHW5w4R6B9Izqo901-5lsC4Zk4lsFjwei0LIKmwknTAvSSJsEvclmhIQ8K9Ike7Yw8JCbAf83lGYvhoU80XJzsq0JhuedXnz5MhnqTDXxoQ&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

then the  response I get is `REQUEST_DENIED`

am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?pagetoken=ClRBAAAAxvr8aF....LiOZ6WQlrmnsux8_icrApjJOIky&location=46.2058000,-1.1645000&radius=500&sensor=false&key=your key here

pagetoken instead of page_token ...