# Google Places API: Does textSearch supports multiple page results?

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get next page of results from textSearch call using next_page_token parameter but always get REQUEST DENIED error. According to [Accessing Additional Results in google places search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248434/accessing-additional-results-in-google-places-search) there is bug in documentation and pagetoken should be used instead of page_token. I tried both and it does not work for me. I can't find anywhere in documntation if multiple pages results available for textSearch.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample query so I can help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: For example, First query:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?key={your api key here}&sensor=false&query=restraunt+honolulu&language=en
It returns list of results and also next_page_token at the end.
Next query:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?pagetoken=CjQrAAAAVkvSstKrrbE3Sk4ETTEnVCRTz6alDNtqwX6471eWfwCQxhcZlqUyTK5w6UcnbSH_EhCWGO82iXeLsD4j1PNXksK-GhRixQLQWkoO1V8N0TDOiye0FsnQzg&key={your api key here}

I tried with page_token and pagetoken and in both cases it returns :<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"sensor" parameter should be specified for next page query. According to documentation "Setting pagetoken will cause any other parameters to be ignored" and this is not true, you have to specifiy "sensor" and "key" parameters.